# Storing orc format through Spark in java

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, orc

I am using spark 1.3.1 and i want to store data in hive as a ORC format..

Below lines showing error, it looks like orc is not supporing as a data source in spark 1.3.1

```
dataframe.save("/apps/hive/warehouse/person_orc_table_5", "orc");

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class for data source: orc
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ddl.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.save(DataFrame.scala:1196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.save(DataFrame.scala:1156)
    at SparkOrcHive.main(SparkOrcHive.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Spark 1.4 has..

```
write.format("orc").partitionBy("age").save("peoplePartitioned")
```

to stored as an orc format..

Is there any way to store file in ORC format in spark 1.3.1 ??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(
    dataframe.select("name", "age")
    .save("/apps/hive/warehouse/orc_table", 
          "org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc", 
          SaveMode.Append);
)
```

Edit :

I am fetching txt file from hdfs and writing data into hive table in orc format. and below code is working fine for me in spark 1.3.1

java class

```
package com.test.spark;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;

/**
 * Created by ankit on 08/02/16.
 */
public class SparkOrcHiveInsert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String tableName = "person_orc";
        String tablePath = "/apps/hive/warehouse/" + tableName;

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ORC Demo").setMaster("local");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

        HiveContext hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc.sc());

        JavaRDD<Person> people = sc.textFile("hdfs://~:8020/tmp/person.txt").map(
                new Function<String, Person>() {
                    public Person call(String line) throws Exception {
                        return process(line);
                    }
                });


        DataFrame schemaPeople = hiveContext.createDataFrame(people, Person.class);
        schemaPeople.select("id","name", "age").save(tablePath, "org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc", SaveMode.Append);
    }

    private static Person process(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(Integer.parseInt(parts[0].trim()));
        person.setName(parts[1]);
        person.setAge(Integer.parseInt(parts[2].trim()));

        return person;
    }
}
```

Hive table script

```
create table person_orc (
  id int,
  name string,
  age int
) stored as orc tblproperties ("orc.compress"="NONE");
```

Spark submit command

```
~/spark/bin/spark-submit --master local  --class com.test.spark.SparkOrcHiveInsert spark-orc-hive-1.0.jar
```

Comment: when i use org.apache.spark.sql.hive.orc in save method, spark throws exception as Failed to load class for data source. using scala for spark 1.3.1

Comment: How are you submitting spark application ?

Comment: @AdamRight, I have edited my answer and its just working fine for me.